# Combine div borders with border radius for different children

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, styled-components, border-radius

I am working on a project where I have to create border-lines between divs that look like these  --[Design-jpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b7Re.png)

But so far I reached[output-jpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dg8c5.png) here

where I can't merge them properly

CSS code

```
export const Container = styled.div`
    &:nth-child(even){
        justify-content: right;
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
        text-align: right;
        border-right: 3px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
        border-top-right-radius: 30px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
        position: relative;

    }
    &:nth-child(odd){
        border: 3px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
        border-radius: 30px  30px;
        border-right: none;
    }`
```

React-HTML

```html
<Container>
 {N.map((elementInArray, index) => (
        <Bunch key={index}>
            <Box className={'box'+elementInArray}>
                <InnerBox/>
            </Box>
            <TextBox2 className={'textbox'+elementInArray}>
                <Heading1>{year}</Heading1>
                <Heading3>{'Q' + elementInArray}</Heading3>
                <Para>{text}</Para>
            </TextBox2>
        </Bunch>
    )
    )}
</Container>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show the basic HTML structure you have to work with. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sure, Please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pure HTML, CSS code**

```css
    body {
        background-color: #080e10;
    }

    main {
        padding: 0 60px;
        margin: 100px 0;
        position: relative;
    }

    .container {
        min-height: 200px;
        position: relative;
        top: -6px;
    }

    .container:nth-child(odd) {
        border: 3px solid #121f28;
        border-left: none;
        border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
        width: calc(100% - 20px);
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-bottom: -6px;
    }

    .container:nth-child(even) {
        border: 3px solid #121f28;
        border-right: none;
        border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
        width: calc(100% - 20px);
        margin-right: auto;
        top: -3px;
    }

    main::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        border: 3px solid #121f28;
        border-top: none;
        border-right: none;
        border-radius: 0 0 0 20px;
        width: calc(100% - 140px);
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-bottom: -6px;
        height: 100px;
        top: -106px;
    }

    main::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        border: 3px solid #121f28;
        border-bottom: none;
        border-right: none;
        border-radius: 20px 0 0 0;
        width: calc(100% - 140px);
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-bottom: -6px;
        height: 100px;
        bottom: -88px;
    }

    .box {
        width: 140px;
        height: 90px;
        background-color: #13232a;
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 10px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .container:nth-child(odd) .box {
        right: -65px;
        margin-left: auto;
        top: 50px;
    }

    .container:nth-child(even) .box {
        left: -65px;
        margin-right: auto;
        top: 50px;

    }

    .circle {
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #465157;
        border: 5px solid #70797e;
    }

    .container:nth-child(odd) .item {
        text-align: end;
        padding-right: 140px;
    }

    .container:nth-child(even) .item {
        text-align: start;
        padding-left: 140px;
    }

    .item h1 {
        margin: none;
        color: #d1d3d4;
    }

    .item h3 {
        margin: none;
        color: #00b6b9;
    }

    .item p {
        text-align: justify;
        color: #414548;
    }
```

```html
 <main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="circle"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <h1>2023</h1>
                <h3>Q1</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe eius nihil totam esse ratione ullam
                    molestias ad ea, sunt minima tempora magnam veritatis voluptate dicta! Odit voluptatem eaque dicta
                    molestiae?
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="circle"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <h1>2023</h1>
                <h3>Q2</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe eius nihil totam esse ratione ullam
                    molestias ad ea, sunt minima tempora magnam veritatis voluptate dicta! Odit voluptatem eaque dicta
                    molestiae?
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="circle"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <h1>2023</h1>
                <h3>Q3</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe eius nihil totam esse ratione ullam
                    molestias ad ea, sunt minima tempora magnam veritatis voluptate dicta! Odit voluptatem eaque dicta
                    molestiae?
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Very good use of the Pseudo elements. I just have to follow that and convert it to react and styled-components